# Implementing multiple fragments in a single activity Dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

### I am working on fragments

---

**Use case i am trying to implement**::

- I am using dynamic fragments
- I am using three fragments in a single activity
- my goal is to communicate between all the three fragments
- I am using support package for fragments

---

Each fragment has a single widget

- `my_fragment1` has `edittext`
- `my_fragment2` has `button`
- `my_fragment3` has `TextView`

---

### On click of `button` the text from the `edittext` must be displayed in the `textview`

---

***What i have tried so far i have constructed most of the scenario below***

---

**Top_Fragment.java**

```
public class Top_Fragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment1, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**Middle_Fragment.java**

```
package com.example.deleteme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Middle_Fragment extends Fragment{

    View view;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment2, container, false);
        btn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Bottom_Fragment.java**

```
public class Bottom_Fragment extends Fragment{

    View view;
    TextView display_text;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment3, container,false);
        display_text=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        return view;
    }

    public void setName(String Name){
        display_text.setText("Result::" + Name);
    }



}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Top_Fragment frg=new Top_Fragment();//create the fragment instance for the top fragment
        Middle_Fragment frg1=new Middle_Fragment();//create the fragment instance for the middle fragment
        Bottom_Fragment frg2=new Bottom_Fragment();//create the fragment instance for the bottom fragment

        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();//create an instance of fragment manager

        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();//create an instance of Fragment-transaction

        transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_1_ID, frg, "Frag_Top_tag");
        transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_2_ID, frg1, "Frag_Middle_tag");
        transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_3_ID, frg2, "Frag_Bottom_tag");


        transaction.commit();

    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@color/black">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_1_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" 
        android:background="@color/yellow">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_2_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/My_Container_1_ID"
        android:background="@color/Orange" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/My_Container_3_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/My_Container_2_ID"
        android:background="@color/purple" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/green" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_fragment2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/pink">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my_fragment3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My output is Like below** ::

[image]

---

**What I am having problem in achieving** ::

- I am not able to set the value obtained from `edit text` to
  `textview` on click of the `button`

**Any Ideas?**

Comment: where do you call `setName(String Name)` ??

Comment: pls check the docs. there is an example. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Comment: no you need not do like that. wait i will post an answer and you need not have fragment 2 which is just a button

Comment: i have changed a few thigns i have not used colors as background i have not used middle fragment which i feel is unnecessary and i have added button in myfragmet1. check the post now

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ....But Edittext, button, TextView all three must be in three different fragments .... Here Edittext and button are in single fragment .... Any thoughts on this ..... reason i am trying to to do is .... i want to know how data flows on events from  frag1 ---> frag2 ---> frag3 ... any guidance on this

Comment: you need button is top fragment to get the editext value. you get the value of editext on some action so you need button in top fragment. second button in middle fragment is useless unnecessary. third to understand flow you need to know how to comuniate between fragments via activity which is what is done here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

`test.java` // in your case its `MainActivity`

```
public class test extends FragmentActivity implements textEntered {

    String value;
    boolean check = false;
    BottomFragment frg2;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Top_Fragment frg = new Top_Fragment();
        frg2 = new BottomFragment();

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_1_ID, frg, "Frag_Top_tag");
        transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_3_ID, frg2, "Frag_Bottom_tag");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String editextvalue) {
        value = editextvalue;
        if (frg2 != null) {
            frg2.setName(value);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fragment 2  is null", 1000).show();
        }
    }

}
```

`Top_Fragment.java`

```
public class Top_Fragment extends Fragment {
    textEntered mCallback;
    Button b;
    EditText ed;

    public interface textEntered {
        public void setValue(String editextvalue);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment1, container, false);
        ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s = ed.getText().toString();
                mCallback.setValue(s);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (textEntered) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +
                " must implement textEntered");
        }
    }
}
```

`my_fragment1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Change to

```
 display_text=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 // id is textView 1 not editText1
```

in BottomFragment

snap

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I understood most of the the things ..... but what is mcallback .... and why are you implementing textentered ..... can give a note in laymen terms !

Comment: @smriti3 it is anitnerface used as a call back. you define the interface in your fragment and implement it in your activity.`textentered` is an interface

Answer (score 8):

**Communication between Fragments**

There can be many scenarios where communication between fragment is required. You need to pass data between fragments on button click event. You may also use Android toolbar to switch between fragments. When you add buttons to your toolbar, you need to dynamically change screen using fragment.

Create an **interface** which will help us to communicate

**Communicate.java**

```
package com.example.amaanmemon.testfragment;

interface Communicate {
 public void sendData();
}
```

**TopFragment.java**

```
package com.example.amaanmemon.testfragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TopFragment extends Fragment {

EditText  firstName;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment1, container, false);
    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    firstName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}

public String getData(){
    return firstName.getText().toString();
}
}
```

**MiddleFragment.java**

```
package com.example.amaanmemon.testfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MiddleFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

View view;
Button btn;
Communicate cm;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment2, container, false);
    return  view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    cm = (Communicate) getActivity();
    btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cm.sendData();
}
}
```

**BottomFragment.java**

```
package com.example.amaanmemon.testfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BottomFragment extends Fragment{

int count;
View view;
TextView display_text;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment3, container,false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    display_text = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}

public void incrementData(String displayText){
    display_text.setText(displayText);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.amaanmemon.testfragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicate{

TopFragment frg;
MiddleFragment frg1;
BottomFragment frg2;
FragmentTransaction transaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frg = new TopFragment();
    frg1 = new MiddleFragment();
    frg2 = new BottomFragment();

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_1_ID, frg, "Frag_Top_tag");
    transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_2_ID, frg1, "Frag_Middle_tag");
    transaction.add(R.id.My_Container_3_ID, frg2, "Frag_Bottom_tag");
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void sendData() {
    String temp = frg.getData();
    frg2.incrementData(temp);
}
}
```

You can copy xml files from question.
you can watch the output below.

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Activity for that.

in the onClick of the bottom fragment you can do something like

`((MainActivity) getActivity()).doIt();`

And make a method `doIt` in your `MainActivity` maybe something like this

```
public void doIt(){
    frg2.setName(frg.getText())
}
```

and in the top fragment make a method `getText` that returns the text of the EditText