# Update Fragment B after onClick on Fragment A using an Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I have been able to instantiate the `Fragment A` click inside the `BaseAdapter` by doing the following

**Fragment A**

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems, 4);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
 if(listType==4)
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout2, null);

                Button keyboard_1 = (Button)
                        convertView.findViewById(R.id.keyboard_1);

                keyboard_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                    }
                });
            }
```

But after the click, I need to update a `View` on `Fragment B`.
If you look at the image, it explains in a very simple way.

[image]

How can we get a `View` instance from `Fragment B` inside the `Adapter`?

Comment: Fragment A communicate to Activity. Then from Activity to Fragment B. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722979/implementing-multiple-fragments-in-a-single-activity-dynamically. answered long time back see if it fits your requirement