# What's the ideal way to manage multiple Fragments in a single Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a single Activity, let's say MainActivity.
In onCreate of MainActivity, I'm loading FragmentOne.
`FragmentOne` has a `ListView`, on clicking an item, it loads `FragmentTwo` in `MainActivity`.
Now my problem is, when `MainActivity` is displaying `FragmentTwo` and if `onCreate` of `MainActivity` is called, like after orientation change, etc. `MainActivity` is again loading `FragmentOne`.
Another problem in same flow is of `OptionsMenu`, every time when Fragment is created, it is appending the Menu multiple times. For now I've maintained a flag and taking help of `savedInstance`. Is there any other way?

Please note that I'm **developing sdk** and hence I want **minimal amount of code in Activity**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722979/implementing-multiple-fragments-in-a-single-activity-dynamically

Comment: @SaketMittal I already went through it before, that question is about communication between Fragments, my question is more likely about handling Activity-Fragment life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Check Fragment.setRetainInstance(boolean) :

> public void setRetainInstance (boolean retain)
>
> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation
> (such as from a configuration change). This can only be used with fragments not >in the back stack. If set, the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different >when an activity is recreated:
>
> onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because the >fragment is being detached from its current activity).
> onCreate(Bundle) will not be called since the fragment is not being re-created.
> onAttach(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will still be called.

Comment: Not helping, tried this before posting.  
I've this in both Fragments:  
`@Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setRetainInstance(true);  
        Log.d("Fragments", "onCreate of FragmentTwo");  
    }`  
Log is somewhat like this:  
`D/Fragments﹕ onCreate of MainActivity  
D/Fragments﹕ onCreate of FragmentOne  
D/Fragments﹕ onCreate of FragmentTwo`  
After rotating the screen  
`D/Fragments﹕ onCreate of MainActivity  
D/Fragments﹕ onCreate of FragmentOne`

Comment: @SwapnilBhoite Anyway, why does your activity should not reload the fragment ? [You could check the doc about runtime change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I created demo for multiple fragment in single activity.
[MultiFragment](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/MultiFragment)

It is easy to use you have to pass id of layout in which you want to place your fragment in [getContentId](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/MultiFragment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kishan/multifragment/MainActivity.java#L25).

Now whenever you want to load fragment in your Activity or Fragment just call [loadFragment](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/MultiFragment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kishan/multifragment/MainActivity.java#L20) or [loadFragmentForResult](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/MultiFragment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kishan/multifragment/DemoButtonFragment.java#L38).