# Error Click Button for move another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

im create some button in fragment A, and when im click this **rekomendasi button** it will move to another fragment(frgment B) but idk whats wrong wtih my code and when im click the **rekomendasi** **button** will unfortunatelly stopped, pls someone take a look

Reference [gvsharma answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212162/how-to-move-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment-on-click-of-a-imageview-in-and)

fragmentA.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);

        Button hitung = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hitung);
        final EditText height = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.height);
        final EditText weight = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        final TextView result = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
        final TextView finalresult = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.finalresult);
        finalresult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        final Button rekomendasi = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rekomendasi);
        rekomendasi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        hitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);


                ......................
                ......................
                }
            }
        });

        rekomendasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = new ArmFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentA, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }




    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Here my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    private static long back_pressed;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis())
            super.onBackPressed();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentA()).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_calculator) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentA()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_abdominal) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentB()).commit();
                }



                return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
}
```

Log Error

```
05-13 21:38:38.340 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0c009c (com.felix.tirtagympool:id/nav_abdominal) for fragment ArmFragment{17785071 #1 id=0x7f0c009c}
05-13 21:38:38.341 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
05-13 21:38:38.341 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity 86502be State:
05-13 21:38:38.341 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     mCreated=truemResumed=true mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
05-13 21:38:38.341 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     mLoadersStarted=true
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:   Active Fragments in f22de56:
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     #0: CalculatorFragment{1e1b0ed7 #0 id=0x7f0c006c}
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0c006c mContainerId=#7f0c006c mTag=null
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mState=5 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
05-13 21:38:38.342 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
05-13 21:38:38.343 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{f22de56 in HostCallbacks{215503c4}}
05-13 21:38:38.343 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@215503c4
05-13 21:38:38.343 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{5f082ad V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1677 #7f0c006c app:id/containerView}
05-13 21:38:38.343 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{e0689e2 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1677}
05-13 21:38:38.343 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mInnerView=android.widget.LinearLayout{e0689e2 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1677}
05-13 21:38:38.343 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       Child FragmentManager{3d97c173 in CalculatorFragment{1e1b0ed7}}:
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:         FragmentManager misc state:
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:           mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@215503c4
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:           mContainer=android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1@8809830
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:           mParent=CalculatorFragment{1e1b0ed7 #0 id=0x7f0c006c}
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:           mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     #1: ArmFragment{17785071 #1 id=0x7f0c009c}
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0c009c mContainerId=#7f0c009c mTag=null
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mState=1 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=1
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{f22de56 in HostCallbacks{215503c4}}
05-13 21:38:38.344 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@215503c4
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:   Added Fragments:
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     #0: CalculatorFragment{1e1b0ed7 #0 id=0x7f0c006c}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     #1: ArmFragment{17785071 #1 id=0x7f0c009c}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:   Back Stack Indices:
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     #0: BackStackEntry{323f9ca9 #0}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@215503c4
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@215503c4
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1a87622e V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1920}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       android.widget.LinearLayout{292301cf V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1920}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{238f075c G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #10203b5}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:         android.widget.FrameLayout{54c5a65 V.E..... ... 0,75-1080,1920}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:           android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{142b733a V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1845 #7f0c0055 app:id/action_bar_root}
05-13 21:38:38.345 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat{2c77ebeb G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f0c0056 app:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:             android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{1bb33d48 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1845 #1020002 android:id/content}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:               android.widget.LinearLayout{15ad37e1 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1845}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{1acd8906 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,168 #7f0c006a app:id/toolbar}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.TextView{9e75bc7 V.ED.... ... 180,43-631,124}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.ImageButton{3862e5f4 VFED..C. ... 0,0-168,168}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{32e4711d VFE..... ... 0,168-1080,1845 #7f0c006b app:id/drawerLayout}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.FrameLayout{5f082ad V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1677 #7f0c006c app:id/containerView}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                     android.widget.LinearLayout{e0689e2 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1677}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{1f292f92 V.E..... ... 0,0-1080,1677}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{2df3ed63 V.E..... ... 92,0-988,330}
05-13 21:38:38.346 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{20c26d60 V.ED.... ... 0,150-896,330 #7f0c0043 app:id/title}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{285c0219 V.E..... ... 171,330-909,514}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{3026b2de V.ED.... ... 0,30-264,151 #7f0c0081 app:id/TextView}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{adfcbf VFED..CL ... 264,0-738,184 #7f0c0082 app:id/height}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{7d0ff8c V.E..... ... 163,514-916,698}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{3421a6d5 V.ED.... ... 0,30-279,151 #7f0c0083 app:id/textView1}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{10e71eea VFED..CL F.. 279,0-753,184 #7f0c0084 app:id/weight}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{30cfa5db V.E..... ... 100,698-980,902}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{2f548878 VFED..C. ... 0,0-398,204 #7f0c0085 app:id/hitung}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{2d62db51 VFED..C. ..P 398,0-880,204 #7f0c0086 app:id/rekomendasi}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{23903fb6 V.E..... ... 303,902-777,1023}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{1498c4b7 VFED..CL ... 0,0-474,121 #7f0c0087 app:id/result}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{2d85b424 V.E..... ... 0,1023-1080,1677}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{16a8db8d VFED.VCL ... 0,0-1080,654 #7f0c0088 app:id/finalresult}
05-13 21:38:38.347 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView{34d8a142 I.E..... ... -840,-71-0,1677 #7f0c006d app:id/shitstuff}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                     android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView{3c6af553 VFED.V.. ... 0,0-840,1748 #7f0c0073 app:id/design_navigation_view}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.widget.LinearLayout{217bee90 V.E..... ... 0,0-840,504 #7f0c0072 app:id/navigation_header_container}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.LinearLayout{17d4a389 V.E..... ... 0,0-840,480}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{34538f8e V.ED.... ... 48,48-792,270 #7f0c008a app:id/imageView}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{132593af V.ED.... ... 48,270-663,375}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                           android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{25963bc V.ED.... ... 48,375-348,432 #7f0c008b app:id/textView}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{1bdaef45 VFED..C. ... 0,504-840,648}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{257d169a V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{2841bbcb V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{3536ffa8 VFED..C. ... 0,648-840,792}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{e403ac1 V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{15860266 V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.348 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{3fae49a7 VFED..C. ... 0,792-840,936}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{15d06e54 V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{3454c1fd V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{21dfdef2 VFED..C. ... 0,936-840,1080}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{36bd943 V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{1df01bc0 V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{23e07b2c VFED..C. ... 0,1080-840,1224}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{1e3080f9 V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{1b88f83e V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{1fe5a2df VFED..C. ... 0,1224-840,1368}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{32e8c69f V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{179b33ec V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                       android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView{23ba9d7e VFED..C. ... 0,1368-840,1512}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView{2b6f33b5 V.ED.... ... 48,0-792,144 #7f0c0074 app:id/design_menu_item_text}
05-13 21:38:38.349 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:                         android.widget.FrameLayout{13185a4a V.E..... ... 792,0-792,144 #7f0c0076 app:id/design_menu_item_action_area}
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/FragmentManager:       android.view.View{2c1d2dbb V.ED.... ... 0,0-1080,75 #102002f android:id/statusBarBackground}
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.felix.tirtagympool, PID: 28360
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c009c (com.felix.tirtagympool:id/nav_abdominal) for fragment ArmFragment{17785071 #1 id=0x7f0c009c}
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5264)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
05-13 21:38:38.350 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
05-13 21:39:17.461 28360-28360/com.felix.tirtagympool I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28360 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the ArmFragment and also the activity's layout xml? 

Did you inflate its layout in the onCreateView() method?

Comment: you are add fragment inside the fragment that is reason for crashing your app... plz show  MainActivity(Your acitivity ) post code...

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19724006/3678308

Comment: Added `MainActivity` guys

Comment: @qwerty123 layout for ?
im only want to focus when im click rekomendasi buttin in FragmentA so user will move into FragmentB

Comment: Do you want your FragmentB inside FragmentA or FragmentB replace FragmentA?

Comment: hi @Elye i want FragmentB replace Fragment A :D

Comment: From the above it seems like you are making ArmFragment on top of FragmentA, which differs from what you want. If you want FragmentB replace FragmentA, all has to be handled by the activity. FragmentA onClick has to call back to the activity to perform the actual replace work.

Comment: @Elye so its impossible to replace FragmentA using FragmentB? and must called Activity to replace FragmentA?

Comment: Suggest you create a simple fragment and test it out first, before going for such complicated code, which make debugging hard. With the simple fragment codes, if you face problem, then you could post here, and easier for us to propose solution.

Comment: @Elye im just curious for this problem haha, but its okay thanks buddy ill try to make a simple one first :)