# setContentView cannot be resolved for FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an error stating:

> setContentView(int) cannot be resolved

for the following class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   <--- ERROR
  }
}
```

FragmentActivity extends Activity, so why is this error happening, and how can I avoid it?

Here is my **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.chris.bluetooth.me.bluetooth.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/aircraft"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/communication"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/communication"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connexion"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connexion"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/communication"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/aircraft"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/connexion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connect"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="Client"
            android:textOn="Client"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/serveur"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="Serveur"
            android:textOn="Serveur"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/disconnect"
        android:text="Connect"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/disconnect"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Disconnect"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The only compile time error seems to be the error I pointed out.

Comment: can you post your `activity_main.xml` and is there no compile-time errors?

Comment: I just added the edits!

Comment: @Chris pls post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that "restart and invalidate caches" fixed the problem. Not sure why this happened, but the error disappeared. I figured this out because I tried to find the stacktrace by building the project, and gradle threw no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a **FragmentActivity** for what are you doing into your activity_main.xml.

Try to extend to AppCompatActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity { }
```

If you really needs FragmentActivity, here there is a complete example of that.

[Implementing multiple fragments in a single activity Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722979/implementing-multiple-fragments-in-a-single-activity-dynamically)

Comment: I'm trying to copy this example for this library: 

https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/blob/master/Bluetooth/Bluetooth_sample/src/main/java/com/ramimartin/sample/multibluetooth/MainActivity.java

and this BluetoothFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity, so I really do need FragmentActivity. I feel like I'm copying this sample verbatim, but I am getting the error I described above.